# Why does "cout << ++Object;" produce an error? (Both << and ++ have been overloaded)

Tags: c++, class, reference, operator-overloading, pre-increment

In the code below, both `<<` and `++` operators *have been overloaded:*

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test{
public:
    int num=0;
    Test operator++(){
      num++;
      return *this;
    }
};

ostream &operator<<(ostream &mystream, Test &x){
    mystream << x.num;
    return mystream;
}
```

When I increase the value of num inside the main(), using the expression `++a;` **before cout**, the code executes completely fine:

```
int main(){
    Test a;
    ++a;
    cout << a << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I try to increase the value of num, **after the `<<` operator**:

```
int main(){
    Test a;
    cout << ++a << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The following error is being produced each time I run the code:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'Test')
    cout << ++a << endl;
    ~~~~ ^  ~~~
```

Why does this happen and what could I do about this?

Comment: First thing I'd change is `Test& operator++()`.  Second thing I'd change is `ostream& operator<<(ostream& mystream, Test const& x)` because otherwise `Test&` tells me and the compiler that the function is going to change `x`.

Comment: @Eljay you'd be right and solve the issue as well, because that non-`const` reference is trying to bind to the temporary returned by `++`, hence the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The prefix `operator++` defined in your class:

```
Test operator++(){
  num++;
  return *this;
}
```

returns a *temporary* object of the type `Test`.

However, the overloaded `operator<<` expects an lvalue reference to an object of the class:

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &mystream, Test &x){
```

You cannot bind an lvalue reference to a temporary object.

You could, for example, either define the `operator++` in the following way (and it should be defined that way):

```
Test& operator++(){
  ++num;
  return *this;
}
```

Or/and define the `operator<<` in the following way:

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &mystream, const Test &x){
    mystream << x.num;
    return mystream;
}
```

providing a constant lvalue reference that can bind to a temporary object.

Comment: Got it, thank you very much! However, why is the first case (where `++a;` executes before `cout<<`) not affected by this as well?

Comment: @Giorgos Because you are using  the same a as lvalue not the expression ++a that returns a temporary object.